# Django QuerySet TypeError

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

we are getting the weirdest error ever. Our whole dev team was on this for the past two days and we cannot get over it.

We have our DRF serializer with a following function:

```
def get_custom_fields(self, obj):
    custom_fields = obj.company.ticketcustomfieldtype_set.all()
    return [{
        'id': field.id,
        'name': str(field.name),
        'type': field.type,
        'value': obj.custom_fields[str(field.id)] if str(field.id) in obj.custom_fields else None
    } for field in custom_fields]
```

`custom_fields` there is a regular Django QuerySet

Now the weird thing: On localhost, this works just fine. On remote, it works fine only when the QuerySet is empty. If there is something in it, we get the following error:

*TypeError: string indices must be integers*

[image]

It appears that the `custom_fields` is now a string. We have no idea why, because on local it works just fine...

- Django 1.11.5
- DRF 3.6.4
- Python 3.4.3
- Postgres 9.6.5

Any help much appreciated, getting desperate :(

EDIT:

TicketCustomFieldType model:

```
class TicketCustomFieldType(models.Model):
    TICKET_CUSTOM_FIELD_TYPES = (
        ('CHAR', _('Text field')),
        ('DATE', _('Date field'))
    )

    TICKET_DEFAULT_CUSTOM_FIELD_TYPE = 'CHAR'

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)

    company = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Company,
        verbose_name=_('Company')
    )

    name = I18nCharField(
        verbose_name=_('Name'),
        max_length=80,
    )

    type = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('Field type'),
        max_length=20,
        choices=TICKET_CUSTOM_FIELD_TYPES,
        default=TICKET_DEFAULT_CUSTOM_FIELD_TYPE,
        help_text=_('In this field, you can store either text, or date value.'),
    )

    priority = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Ticket model (abbreviated):

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
(...)
class Ticket(models.Model):
    (...)
    custom_fields = JSONField(encoder=DjangoJSONEncoder, default=dict, verbose_name=_('Custom fields'))

    def get_custom_field(self, field_type):
        qs = self.customfields.filter(type=field_type)
        if qs.exists():
            return qs.first()

        new_field = TicketCustomField()
        new_field.ticket = self
        new_field.type = field_type
        new_field.save()
        return new_field

    def get_all_custom_fields(self):
        custom_fields = []
        for type in self.company.ticketcustomfieldtype_set.all():
            custom_fields.append(self.get_custom_field(type))
        return custom_fields
```

EDIT 2:

After upgrading to Python 3.6, this problem got fixed, no changes to the code...

Comment: It'd be helpful to see your model definitions, could you add it to the question?

Comment: The error suggests that `obj.custom_fields` is a list, not a dictionary. Therefore you can do `obj.custom_fields[1]`, but `obj.custom_fields[str(1)]` will give you an error.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the models.

Answer (score 0):

Please change this:

```
'value': obj.custom_fields[str(field.id)] if str(field.id) in obj.custom_fields else None
```

to this:

```
'value': obj.custom_fields[field.id] if str(field.id) in obj.custom_fields else None
```

This is because it is expecting an integer, but what you are providing is a string

Comment: Thanks. No, this is not the problem. `custom_fields` should be a `dict` and there's nothing wrong with that construction. The problem is that `custom_fields` is, for some reason, not a `dict`, but a `string`, apparently. The error is in the list comprehension, not in the assignment.

Comment: could post the model structure? And you are calling obj.custom_fields, what does this return?

Comment: Thank you. I have added the models.